# VS 2015 TFS/Git Revert Commits that were Pulled from Remote Branch

Tags: git, github, tfs

Our small team pushes/pulls to/from a shared remote test branch. I need to revert commits that a different user pushed, and that I pulled some months ago. I expect that reverting those commits will only affect the local branch I currently have checked out, but I need to know for sure.

Comment: We can say for sure that any command or combination of commands *excluding `push`* will only affect your local repo.  How different branches are affected depends on how things look now and what commands you use; but bottom line, don't push until you have your local repo in good shape and know what the effect of your push will be.

Comment: Thanks Mark Adelsberger! I didn't expect an answer so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

I did lots of experimenting with several local branches created to track the remote branch, reverting small commits that I had pushed earlier and that had been incorporated into that remote branch. All's well. Reverting a pulled commit only affects the local branch that I currently have checked out.

Answer (score 0):

After some time on this, I am ready to conclude that in practice, the tool doesn’t actually help - at least not in my case.

Reverting and taking Source seems to revert the entire file to its state at that time, several months ago rather than just undoing the code changes, words/characters that were added or deleted, with that commit.

Cherry Pick, Resolve Conflicts, Merge and/or Compare Files is also ham-fisted in that code blocks that were not changed are marked as changed, and changes that were made months later may or may not appear mixed in with the listed Target code.

I have concluded that Reverting is an option worth considering if the commit to be reverted is very recent, and if the entire commit needs to be undone completely.

If there is any detailed material on this, I would like to know where to find it.